# Changing the color of paragraphs in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I have a WPF RichTextBox that reads the log file and displays it on screen.

The text from the log file gets appended as a single paragraph in the RichTextBox. The log file has paragraphs as 'Info', 'Warning', 'Error'.
The paragraphs are separated by --- lines and is seen like this:

```
8/23 17:40:54:761  6948 - Warning - Logging: Set ABC
-----------------------------------------
08/23 17:40:54:772  6948 - Info - Logging: FullFileName:/XYZ/
                           Message:Some Message 
                           Type : Information                          
---------------------------------------------
08/23 17:40:54:844  6948 - Error - Logging: End of Control_Loaded
```

How can I change the color of 'Error' paragraphs to Red and 'Info' paragraphs to green in the entire RichTextbox text that is displayed ?

Here is my WPF RichTextBox box code :

```
<RichTextBox Background='Black' Foreground="White" IsReadOnly="True" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" UndoLimit="0" 
             IsUndoEnabled="False"
             TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" >
             <FlowDocument>
                 <Paragraph>
                     <Run Text="{Binding Contents, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                 </Paragraph>
             </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>

 private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (RichTextBox) (sender);
            var fileMonitorViewModel = ((FileMonitorViewModel) textBox.DataContext);            
            //textBox.ColorParagraphs();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To color paragraphs depend on a text they are started you can use the following method:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

public static class RichTextBoxExt
{
    public static void ColorParagraphs(this RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        // Select all paragraphs 
        var blocks = new List<Paragraph>();
        foreach (var block in rtb.Document.Blocks)
        {
            var para = block as Paragraph;
            if (para != null)
                blocks.Add(para);
        }
    
        // Color paragraphs depend on a text they are started
        foreach (var para in blocks)
        {
            var range = new TextRange(para.ContentStart, para.ContentEnd);
            var text = range.Text;
    
            if (text.StartsWith("Error"))
            {
                range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
            }
            else if (text.StartsWith("Info"))
            {
                range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Victor, I am finding an error 'The name para does not exist in the current context'. I upgraded the project framework to .NET 4.8 but the error is not going away. Is there anything missing in the code ?

Comment: @DotNetSpartan: What is version of the Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @DotNetSpartan: VS2015 is c# 6.0  I fixed 3 lines of code: will be compiled for VS 2015. Try again, please.

Comment: Thanks @Victor, I am able to build on VS 2015 now, I added the extension and used it in the TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged() method. The color on paragraph is not seen. I've updated my code in the question. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @DotNetSpartan: Works for me from the `TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged()`. Try to type Error in a new line. Does it work? And use debugger to check that when you enter some text you can observe the text in `var text = range.Text;` line.

Comment: No it didn't worked, I could see at var text = range.Text; that the text is the entire text of log file. That text has lot of rows separated by ------ lines and that text starts with 'Transaction' row just like in the screenshot from the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247476/discussion-between-dotnetspartan-and-victor).